# Object.defineProperty not working for Array.prototype.contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to use Object.defineProprty for contains but it was throwing error. Sample code and Error msg attached

**Sample Code:**

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    value : function(){
         for (i in this) {
             console.log(i);
         }
         return false;
    }
});
```

**Javascript Error:**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: contains
at Function.defineProperty

Comment: It means what it says. Array.prototype already has a contains property and it is not configurable. If you want to be able to run this more than once (tweaking the descriptor or whatever) you should declare it [as configurable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Configurable_attribute) so you can overwrite it after it's defined.

Comment: It seems you're trying to execute the above code more than once. Don't do that

Comment: Also, I assume you're aware of [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)?

Comment: @ray hatfield Thanks for your guidance. It really helps... Posted answer.:)

Answer (score 0):

The Array.prototype object already has the "contains" property defined. I'm pretty sure you executed the code more than once. Apparently is not set as writable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! So need to set a configurable as true, since its false by default. If it is false, the property can't be deleted and can't be changed to a data property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_redefine_property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Properties

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    configurable: true,
    value : function(){
         for (i in this) {
             console.log(i);
         }
         return false;
    }
});
```